# Почему не работает xdebug + удаленный сервер?

Tags: php, phpstorm, отладка, xdebug

Есть удаленный проект, хочу использовать Xdebug в PHPStorm для отладки

Настройки:

PHP 5.4

php.ini:

```
zend_extension = "/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_host={МОЙ_IP}
xdebug.idekey=PHP_IDE_CONFIG

xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM2"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ставлю breakpoint'ы в index.php, запускаю отладку,в браузере открывается главная страница, но консоль отладки пустая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю неправильно? Куда копать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. На втором скрине есть кнопка "validate...", предлагаю ей воспользоваться, чтобы исключить проблемы со стороны сервера
2. [Убедись](http://portchecker.co/check), что до твоего компьютера проходят входящие соединения на порт 9000
3. [Букмарклет](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/) генератор от авторов позволит включать необходимое по запросу, а не всегда стартовать автоматически
4. Если совсем всё тяжко с пробросом, можно коннектиться по ssh на сервер и [форвардить](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#3.5) локальный порт, в этом случае в xdebug.remote_port лучше указать незадействованный порт, а
   xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
5. ни разу не пробовал коннектиться по IPv6, но может тоже оказаться решением проблемы, если настроить поддержку по всему пути

Comment: Спасибо, получилось только через проброс порта к локальному ПК